# No way to resolve conflict between log4net from GAC and log4net from project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, gac

I'm developing a C# library project with .NET Framework 4.6.2 and log4net 2.0.8.

When I try to compile the project I get the following error:

> error CS0433: The type 'log4net.ILog' exists in
>   'c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32\log4net\1.2.10.0__692fbea5521e1304\log4net.dll'
>   and also in
>   'd:\Desarrollo\packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll'

It seems that there is another version of log4net in GAC.

Why does it use the GAC version to compile? I have another projects with log4net and only in this one I get this error.

The reference for log4net is `D:\Desarrollo\packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll`. And it sets as local copy.

I have installed the package and added again with the same error.

The detailed error is this:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1964,5): warning MSB3243: No way to resolve conflict between "log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" and "log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304". Choosing "log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" arbitrarily.
1>D:\MyProject\Loggers\ActionLogHelper.cs(28,20,28,24): error CS0433: The type 'ILog' exists in both 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' and 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
1>D:\MyProject\Loggers\ActionLogHelper.cs(30,26,30,30): error CS0433: The type 'ILog' exists in both 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' and 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
1>D:\MyProject\Loggers\ExceptionLogHelper.cs(22,20,22,24): error CS0433: The type 'ILog' exists in both 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' and 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
1>D:\MyProject\Loggers\ExceptionLogHelper.cs(24,29,24,33): error CS0433: The type 'ILog' exists in both 'log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' and 'log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a'
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Use Nuget for log4net and it will reference the DLL via the bin folder

Comment: What does your reference to log4net look like?

Comment: I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: It does not use the GAC to compile.  It uses the references of the project.  All of them, not just the one you hoped it will use.  This probably went wrong a while ago, ought to coincide when somebody (or you) took a shortcut he shouldn't have made and told you to register the assembly to get this project built.  It does not belong in the GAC.

Comment: AFAIK, if it has the same version number as the referenced DLL, the GAC gets used. How about delete the one in the temporary files for sure? Then you can decide if you want to remove the one from the GAC probably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were two references to the same dll in the project file. I have opened the project file with Notepad++ and I have found this inside:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="log4net, Version=2.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\log4net.2.0.8\lib\net45-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Ninject, Version=3.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c7192dc5380945e7, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\Ninject.3.2.2.0\lib\net45-full\Ninject.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
    <Reference Include="log4net">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\packages\log4net.2.0.3\lib\net40-full\log4net.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

I have removed the last one, and now it compiles.